# Serverless Framework with Cloudfront and Lambda@Edge functions

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework

I'm using this serverless yaml below and I'm trying to deploy a cloudfront app with a lambda@edge viewer-request and origin request labdas.

I can get the two lambdas to deploy if i exclude any cloudfront yaml directives. But when I add cloudfront  directives `sls deploy` errors out with this:

```
Could not find resource with logical name "CloudFrontDistribution"
```

which is very generic and googling is limited.

What am i missing with generating Cloudfront?

Here is my yml and thanks in advance!:

```
service: ${file(serverless-config/vars-config.yml):service}
custom:
   objectPrefix: '${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}'
   scripts:
     hooks:
       package:initialize: make compile
plugins:
  - '@silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge'
  - serverless-plugin-scripts
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  stage: production
  profile: production
  timeout: 300
  region: ${file(serverless-config/vars-config.yml):region}
functions:
   viewerRequestPostGetRewriteHandler:
      name: '${self:custom.objectPrefix}-viewer-request'
      handler: app/functions/ViewerRequestPostGetRewriteHandler.main
      memorySize: 128
      timeout: 1
      events:
      lambdaAtEdge:
        distribution: CloudFrontDistribution
        eventType: viewer-request
   originRequestGetPostRewriteHandler:
      name: '${self:custom.objectPrefix}-viewer-request'
      handler: app/functions/OriginRequestGetPostRewriteHandler.main
      memorySize: 128
      timeout: 1
      events:
      lambdaAtEdge:
        distribution: CloudFrontDistribution
        eventType: origin-request
resources:
  Resources:
    CloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          PriceClass: PriceClass_100
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a setup just like yours and it works great. I think the error is correct in a way. The `CloudFrontDistribution`, as you pasted it, is incomplete. Therefore it was not created. The error is poorly communicated to you because it looks like the plugin caught it the problem, rather than the core app.

To prove my theory, go ahead and try launching without the plugin being activated and you should see better errors related to an invalid `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` resource.

To resolve the problem: configure a valid CloudFormation resource. Use the example from here for inspiration:
https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge#example-cloudfront-static-site-serverless-config